# iOS development (play 3gp video as a view background)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background, 3gp

Is there any way to play .3gp video as a view background ?

I have tried :

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xdx2l9ozayy02n/clip1.3gp"]];

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 300);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

but this just doesn't work.